# Codomain and domain dimensions

Tags: functions

In numerous places in **Ordinary Differential Equations with Applications by Chicone (2006 2nd edition)**, I see the general notation $f:\mathbb{R}$ x $\mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$ or

$$J \subset \mathbb{R}, U \subset \mathbb{R^n}, \Lambda \subset \mathbb{R^k}$$ with

$$f:J \times U \times \Lambda \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$$.

How is this possible? Doesn't the dimension of the codomain have to be the sum of the dimensions of the domain, always?$$f:\mathbb{R^m} \times \mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^{m+n}}$$

Comment: That's never required. For example the function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to {0}$ is a well defined function mapping every element to ${0}$. On the other the same function may be defined $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^k$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x,y) = xy$. This maps $\mathbb{R}^2$ (ordered pairs or points) to $\mathbb{R}^1$ (real numbers).

You could consider defining the function I've given as $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $f(x,y) = (xy,0)$. But what does such a definition give you other than a lot of wasted notation? Mathematics is all about delivering the most information in the least amount of notation. So why add to the dimension of the codomain when I know I'm not going to be using those extra dimensions?